# Is it possible to send a unix signal in a Mono C# program?

Tags: c#, mono, signals

I have a C# program that runs on both Windows and Linux. When it runs on Linux, there is another process running on the system that I want to be able to be able to send a command to, and have the process execute the command.

My initial intuition was to implement a signal handler in this other process, and have the C# program send the appropriate signal whenever it wants to interact with it. However, searching around I could not find anything about the functionality to send unix signals existing in the Mono API (I was, however, able to find that Mono supports signal handling, which gave me hope.)

Does this functionality exist as part of the Mono API?

Comment: Have you checked out Mono.Posix library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `Syscall.kill` in the namespace `Mono.Unix.Native` (reference `Mono.Posix`).

#### Example that kills itself with ABRT (6 / abort):

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix.Native;

namespace killself
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var currentPID = Syscall.getpid();
            Syscall.kill(currentPID, Signum.SIGABRT);
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.kill

Comment: And to compile the above code in mono is by: `mcs /reference:Mono.Posix.dll testapp.cs`