# .net-core app: how to send SIGTERM to child processes?

Tags: signals, .net-core

Is it possible for .net-core app running on Linux to send SIGTERM signal to a child process?

We're thinking to port our .net app to .net-core and run it on Linux, to avoid current signal implementation (i.e. sending `CloseMainWindow()` from parent process, and using pywin32 package, and `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` in child processes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by the implementation in https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix.Native/Syscall.cs, here is a utility class that should do what you want

```cs
public static class ProcessUtils
{        
    [DllImport ("libc", SetLastError=true, EntryPoint="kill")]
    private static extern int sys_kill (int pid, int sig);
    
    public static void Kill(this Process process, Signum sig)
    {
        sys_kill(process.Id, (int) sig);
    }
}

public enum Signum : int {
    SIGHUP    =  1, // Hangup (POSIX).
    SIGINT    =  2, // Interrupt (ANSI).
    SIGQUIT   =  3, // Quit (POSIX).
    SIGILL    =  4, // Illegal instruction (ANSI).
    SIGTRAP   =  5, // Trace trap (POSIX).
    SIGABRT   =  6, // Abort (ANSI).
    SIGIOT    =  6, // IOT trap (4.2 BSD).
    SIGBUS    =  7, // BUS error (4.2 BSD).
    SIGFPE    =  8, // Floating-point exception (ANSI).
    SIGKILL   =  9, // Kill, unblockable (POSIX).
    SIGUSR1   = 10, // User-defined signal 1 (POSIX).
    SIGSEGV   = 11, // Segmentation violation (ANSI).
    SIGUSR2   = 12, // User-defined signal 2 (POSIX).
    SIGPIPE   = 13, // Broken pipe (POSIX).
    SIGALRM   = 14, // Alarm clock (POSIX).
    SIGTERM   = 15, // Termination (ANSI).
    SIGSTKFLT = 16, // Stack fault.
    SIGCLD    = SIGCHLD, // Same as SIGCHLD (System V).
    SIGCHLD   = 17, // Child status has changed (POSIX).
    SIGCONT   = 18, // Continue (POSIX).
    SIGSTOP   = 19, // Stop, unblockable (POSIX).
    SIGTSTP   = 20, // Keyboard stop (POSIX).
    SIGTTIN   = 21, // Background read from tty (POSIX).
    SIGTTOU   = 22, // Background write to tty (POSIX).
    SIGURG    = 23, // Urgent condition on socket (4.2 BSD).
    SIGXCPU   = 24, // CPU limit exceeded (4.2 BSD).
    SIGXFSZ   = 25, // File size limit exceeded (4.2 BSD).
    SIGVTALRM = 26, // Virtual alarm clock (4.2 BSD).
    SIGPROF   = 27, // Profiling alarm clock (4.2 BSD).
    SIGWINCH  = 28, // Window size change (4.3 BSD, Sun).
    SIGPOLL   = SIGIO, // Pollable event occurred (System V).
    SIGIO     = 29, // I/O now possible (4.2 BSD).
    SIGPWR    = 30, // Power failure restart (System V).
    SIGSYS    = 31, // Bad system call.
    SIGUNUSED = 31
}
```

Comment: How about: public static void Kill(Signum sig, params System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes) ? Then you can just pass System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("nginx") to the method, and it also works if you just give it a single process.

Comment: @StefanSteiger Of course, it will also work, if your use case is to kill multiple process at once.

Answer (score 0):

The answer *seems* to be NO, unfortunately (and surprisingly).

#### My research:

> Processes can be stopped by calling Process.Kill. On Linux, this is
>   implemented by sending the SIGKILL signal, which tells the kernel to
>   terminate the application immediately. It’s not possible to send a
>   SIGTERM signal, which requests the application to gracefully
>   terminate.

Source: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/29/the-net-process-class-on-linux/

Also, it seems like this has been discussed but has been discarded as "unnecessary":

> Closing in favor of the existing specialized APIs shown directly above
>   by @tmds and for general signal sending and handling with
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/

But `Mono.Posix.NETStandard` doesn't seem allow sending signals to processed by process ID:

> Mono.Posix doesn't let you send a signal to a process given its
>   process ID. It is, therefore, pretty useless for the purpose of this
>   issue.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3188

If anyone has a working solution for the OP's question I'd also be interested in knowing how to do it, if it's possible at all.

Comment: In fact, the `Syscall.kill` has process id as it's first argument, so it can be used to send signals by pid. It's also confirmed by your source (maybe later then you wrote this answer). They reffered to this SO anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809358/2464169